# Can't access apache solr service from application deployed on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Created a google app engine application using spring mvc, right now we are running
it local devAppServer:appengine:devserver, for this application accessing apache
solr server (via http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/solr)its running AWS EC2 istance,

wrote a controller like following

```
String apacheUrl = "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/solr";
SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(apacheUrl);
ModifiableSolrParams parameters = new ModifiableSolrParams();
      parameters.set("q", "*:*"); //query everything thanks to user1452132!         
      parameters.set("fl", "id,propertyName");//send back just the id values
      parameters.set("fq", "cityName:\""+cityName+"\"");//Id like this in json format please
```

can't able to get the results from apache solr ,

google app engine says

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.ProxySelector is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient.createHttpRoutePlanner(SystemDefaultHttpClient.java:135)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getRoutePlanner(AbstractHttpClient.java:677)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:810)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:395)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:199)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
at com.vs.ui.events.controller.ApacheSolrController.getVSPackageServiceID(ApacheSolrController.java:812)
at com.vs.ui.events.controller.GenericController.getPropertyName(GenericController.java:5008)
at com.vs.ui.events.controller.GenericController.getPropertyNameDirectory(GenericController.java:3317)
```

1) Is it anyway to write controller
3) Any permission access required for google app engine

Any suggestions

Comment: Some things you just can't do on GAE. java.net.ProxySelector is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.

Comment: If you want to use restricted classes, you can look at [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/)